# learning OOP in C

Tags: c, oop

I am learning OOP using C. I am getting a

> "warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
>   [-Wint-conversion]" for line 44 (see code comment)

I am using `gcc`. Please explain why I am getting this warning.

Also please recommend a good learning resource for OOP in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct employee {
    int experience;
    double basic_salary;
    double salary;
    char name[20];
    int (*calculate_salary)(int a);
};

typedef struct employee emp;
typedef emp *Employee;

int cal_salary_oop (int exp) {
    int salary = 0;
    if (exp>15)
        salary += 25000;
    else if (exp > 10)
        salary += 15000;
    else if (exp > 5)
        salary += 5000;
    return salary;
}

Employee new_Employee (int experience, int basic_salary) {
    Employee obj = (Employee) malloc (sizeof(emp));
    obj->basic_salary = basic_salary;
    obj->experience = experience;
    obj->calculate_salary =  &cal_salary_oop;
    return obj;
}

void destroy_Employee(Employee e) {
    free(e);
}

int main(void) {

    Employee emp = new_Employee(14,2000);

    int emp_cal_salary = emp->calculate_salary;   // line 44
    printf("emp1 calculated salary like oop way %d\n",emp_cal_salary);

    destroy_Employee(emp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't call the function. You just assigned the pointer value to the `int` variable. To emulate OOP, it's standard practice to pass the object pointer as the first argument to all of the class methods. That way you have access to the member variables `basic_salary` and `experience`.

Comment: What do you mean by "OOP"? For me it means object oriented programming, but C is not famed for its object orientation. So I would like to make sure that we are thinking of the same "OOP".

Comment: @Yunnosch : There's a book named [Object-Oriented Programming With ANSI-C](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf).

Comment: @EmilyE. I do not get your point. I know OOP is possible with C, but I think that is only true if you know both already. But learning OOP using C seems a very tough path to walk. So I kind of hope that OP means something different by "OOP", which might mean OPs life is not going to turn very unpleasant very soon.

Comment: @Yunnosch There are many applications of OOP in C. For example, C library function fopen()

Comment: @TreeCity same comment as above to Emily. I know it is possible.

Comment: Learn OOP in a OO language.  It will be easier on everyone, especially you.

Comment: Somebody should have told those poor fellas over a Gtk+ that a long time ago.... (but I do quite like what they came up with in Version 2)

Comment: It would also make more sense to declare `int (*calculate_salary)(struct employee*);` so you could pass a pointer your struct instance as a the parameter making the `inst->salary` and `inst->experience` available within `cal_salary_oop`. Then you could return the total salary, e.g. `return e->salary + e->basic_salary;` from your function. You would be interested in chapters 2 and 3 of the "OOP with ANSI C" -- link above. Pay attention to why the sizeof the struct is the first member and what problems that solves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In above small error in line no 44

```
int emp_cal_salary = emp->calculate_salary;
```

`emp->calculate_salary` has address of `cal_salary_oop`.

i.e obj->calculate_salary =  &cal_salary_oop;

now you tried to do the same here instead pointer to function you are trying to use int

```
int emp_cal_salary = emp->calculate_salary;
```

you are trying to assign the pointer address to emp_cal_salary  instead of call the function .

try this below line it work

```
int emp_cal_salary = emp->calculate_salary(exp); // i.e exp  =14
```

you cannot assign the memory location to integer variable.